# Dask read_parquet partitions with no metadata

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, dask, parquet

Let's assume I have an S3 bucket with partitioned data stored in it. Such as:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

data_path = 's3://bucket/prefix'

df = pd.DataFrame({'lines': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'area': [1, 1, 20, 20], 'values': [0.1, 0.2, 1.1, 1.2]})
dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2).to_parquet(data_path, partition_on=['lines', 'area'])
```

This generates a directory structure in s3 like this:

```
bucket/prefix
|__lines=0
   |__area=1
      |__ <file>
|__lines=1
   |__area=20
      |__ <file>
|__ _common_metadata
|__ _metadata
```

When I read this using `dask`, everything is OK, since I saved it with `dask` also

```
dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/prefix').compute()

   values  lines    area
0   0.1      0      1
1   0.2      0      1
2   1.1      1      20
3   1.2      1      20
```

**HOWEVER**

My actual data is generated externally (by redshift), and does not include the `_metadata` and `_common_metadata` files. This results in two problems.

### ISSUE 1

I have to find all files under the prefix, otherwise I get error. This gives error:

```
dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/prefix').compute()

~/anaconda3/envs/mars/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet/utils.py in _analyze_paths(file_list, fs, root)
    405     path_parts_list = [_join_path(fn).split("/") for fn in file_list]
    406     if root is False:
--> 407         basepath = path_parts_list[0][:-1]
    408         for i, path_parts in enumerate(path_parts_list):
    409             j = len(path_parts) - 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

### ISSUE 2

After find all files under prefix, and giving a list to `read_parquet`, I do not get the partition columns (lines, area) , and only the `values` column:

```
subfiles = ['s3://bucket/prefix/lines=0/area=1/file', 's3://bucket/prefix/lines=1/area=20/file']
dd.read_parquet(subfiles).compute()


values
0   0.1
1   0.2
2   1.1
3   1.2
```

Any ideas of how to maintain behavior in dask `read_parquet` as if having the metafiles in there so that I have the partition columns and maybe don't have to find all subfiles in a folder?

Comment: Are you using fastparquet or pyarrow? What version of dask do you have?

Comment: I am using pyarrow and dask 2.25

Comment: This has been undergoing a rewrite recently, so the easiers answer may be: update or wait for https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/6772 to be merged and released

Comment: Is there a version of the code which works, which has been already merged? I see requirements on master still requires pyarrow < 2

Comment: I believe the linked PR is the only one with pyarrow 2 support. Gathering from multiple files and inferring the path-based partitions ought to have worked before that too, but will depend on which version pyarrow you use. I believe fastparquet should work.